# Android + Adding layouts Dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic

I have a requirement to show 5 images on the screen & onClick of the Specified image, i'l play music for 3 seconds and then goes to the next activity(or set of another 5 images) randomly.

Like that I have to show upto 16 different views(16*5 images) randomly .....

Upto that I have done & working Quite Decently.

**For that I have created 16 Activities & corresponding 16 Xml files.

My Question is can I add those 16 XML files to the single Activity instead of 16 activities. I just heard about Dynamically adding layouts to Activity.But In my project, I have to change the set of images onClick of correct Image and load new Images , to be clicked...**

To be short & simple  I want to show content from Various resources on The **SINGLE ACTIVITY**...

```
                             (or)
```

Is it better to go with many number of activities possible?

N0te:It may be a simple question, BUt I am googling & searching on this site for the past 8 days, still no result. So please do this favour....

Andd, ** If You geeks wanna give DOWN VOTE, Please specify the Kind reason....**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
setContentView(R.layout.myxmlfile.xml)
```

to load another layout in the same activity

To load them randomly,

get the id of your first and last layout

```
final int first = R.layout.myfirstLayout.xml;
final int last = R.layout.myLastLayout.xml;
```

now generate a random value between these two ints.

```
final int random = (int)(first + (Math.Random()%last));
```

use this random for loading your layout

```
setContentView(random);
```

for this to work, you have to make sure your layouts are ordered correctly, by naming them alphabetically.

Comment: Ok prem, Sorry to trouble you, But I have 16 different Layouts.Please help me to generate a random value between those 16 layouts.

Comment: name your 16 layouts as something similar to randomLayout1.xml, randomLayout2.xml, randomLayout3.xml, ..., randomLayout16.xml. Then the above code should work.

Comment: How can I use thatt code here ""final int random = (first + (Math.Random()%last));
"".... As I have 16 layouts How to put it in Random.

Comment: final int random = (int) (first + (Math.random()%last));

Comment: How sure can you be for the first and the last layouts to be in the same order with other layouts in the project?

Comment: @PrakashNadar They should be if you name them correctly, but your method is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
int layouts[] = { R.layout.layout1, R.layout.layout2, .... }
setRandomLayout() {
   int layout = layouts[random of layouts.length];
   setContentView(layout);
}
```

Also, If all the layouts are going to appear identical, the I would suggest using one layout but different data/image for each image.